# Excel2013 "Cannot open PivotTable source file" during "Update All"

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an old bloated Excel workbook that I am trying to strip down.
After I replaced all the external and computed internal data source with `table`s linked to SQL database queries, every time I do a `Update All`, Excel always complain  `“Cannot open PivotTable source file xxxxxx[yyyy]|zzzz”`

I reviewed nearly every sheet, but failed to find anything referencing the external Excel file in question.  <del>Is there any way to locate which cell, at least in which sheet, this pivotable in question  is?</del>

Looks like the cached data is no longer referenced. (see PS2) 
Is there anyway to purge these cached entries without manually editing the XMLs ?

Thanks.

PS1:
I have tried the VBA way inspecting the ActiveWB.LinkSource(1)
It didn't work, all it gives me is a worksheet referenced in a cell that I already know. The worksheet mentioned in the error alert is not listed.

PS2:
I saved file to xlsx unpackd internal XMLs, a simple grep gives me

```
$ grep '20160229-9' -r .
./xl/pivotCache/_rels/pivotCacheDefinition1.xml.rels:
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.../relationships">
<Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.../externalLinkPath" Target="OrderList20160229-9.xlsb" TargetMode="External"/>
<Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas...relationships/pivotCacheRecords" Target="pivotCacheRecords1.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

But PivotTable1's datasource has already been replaced with a SQL query piped table side by side on the same sheet...

Inspecting the referred pivotCacheRecords1.xml, I got the very old copy of the source table (the new sql query based table has a different format, I can't find the items in these data anywhere in excel either.). Its no longer valid any more. Hmm, is this a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the missing referenced source to an no longer exist pivot table.

- Save it as xlsx. Open with 7z or any other archive manager.
- Extract the folder `xl\pivotCache\_rels\` & inspect the xmls look for xml containing reference to the external source file in question.
- Remove the xml from archive manager & save the resulting xlsx.
- Open the xlsx in Excel and save again, Excel will complain stuff missing and repair the file.

When working with DB linked table as source.
Consider Disable `PivotTableOptions>Data>Save Source data with file`

Done